# Textbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this `textbox` that has the limit in `DB` for input 255. And I am trying to built a function in `JS` that stops the user for inserting more than 255 characters in that textbox.

Here is the asp.net code:

```
<asp:TextBox Id="textbox" TextMode="MultiLine"
             oninput="F(id,this.value.length, 255)"
             runat="server" Columns="25" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
```

And here is the code in `JS`(just a test):

```
this.textCounter = function (ref,value, maxlimit) {
    if (value > maxlimit) {
        $('#textbox').value=" ";
    }
    return true;
}
```

Somehow the `$('#textbox').value` is undefined.
What I can do?

Comment: If you are using `jQuery` then it has method `val` for getting/setting value i.e. `$('#textbox').val("aaaa");` for setting and `$('#textbox').val();` for getting. `value` is a property in javascript and your are using jQuery object thus your code was not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use maxlength HTML property in your asp.net control. and that will work fine.

```
maxlength="255"
```

**Edit:**

```
<asp:TextBox Id="textbox" onKeyPress="return(this.value.length < 255);" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="25" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: @GeorgeGreat can you please paste the full code with MaxLength propety ?

Comment: This one? public virtual int MaxLength { set; get; }
    Member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

Comment: <asp:TextBox Id="textbox" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="255"
             runat="server" Columns="25" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: @GeorgeGreat i have edited my answer and tested it my self, please have a look. with onKeyPress="return(this.value.length < 255);

Answer (score 1):

You should use $('#textbox').html instead of $('#textbox').value.
$('#textbox').html takes the content between the textbox tags. Because a textbox does not has a value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
$("#<%= textbox.ClientID %>").val("myValue")
```

aspnet renames the textbox ID's to make sure there are no duplicates on the client side, so `textbox` can become something like `PlaceHolder1_textbox`. And then your hardcoded javscript reference will not work anymore.

Comment: It says that the syntax is wrong. I must put as well ClientID="static"?

Comment: Using `ClientIDMode="Static"` is not recommended. It can lead to duplicate id's.

Answer (score -1):

When you define your text your have to specified `ClientIDMode="Static"`. In this way .NET create a input box with your name. Usually an input box name is more complex than the name you chose.

Another way is to use a bit of code in the javascript. Instead of `$('#textbox')` you have to use

```
$('#<%= yourtextbox.CliendId%>')
```

Comment: At least make sure the code is correct... `$('#<%= yourtextbox.ClientID %>')`

Comment: Yes. You have to use it in an ASP.NET page